# how to create dataframe from one column in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have sliced out one column of type Column in pyspark.

```
x =game_reviews.groupBy("product_id_index").agg((F.count('star_rating').alias('num')  ) 
x.num
```

gives

```
Column<b'num'>
```

But this

```
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(x.num)
new_df.show()
```

gives error.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is a simple one-liner. Good luck!

```
new_df = game_reviews.groupBy("product_id_index").agg((F.count('star_rating').alias('num')).select("num")
new_df.show()
```